# Why document.execCommand() only works in <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML code:

```
function formatDoc() {
     document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
}

<div id="toolBar2">
    <span onclick="formatDoc();">italic</span>
    <img src="images/video.jpg" onclick="formatDoc();">
</div>
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
```

The `formatDoc()` doesn't work in `<span>` tag, but works well in `<img>` tag.
why?
It also doesn't work in `<p>` tag and so on. So far I unsuccesfully tried to come to a solution by myselfy.

Who can tell me why this is happening? :(
Thanks everybody.

Comment: "works well in img tag" How have you verified that? Does it skew the image? I doubt you've misunderstood the whole concept here. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands): "italic: Toggles italics on/off for the selection or at the insertion point.(Internet Explorer uses the EM tag instead of I.)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from mozilla development network

When an HTML document has been switched to designMode, the document object exposes the execCommand method which allows one to run commands to manipulate the contents of the editable region. Most commands affect the document's selection (bold, italics, etc.), while others insert new elements (adding a link) or affect an entire line (indenting). When using contentEditable, calling execCommand() will affect the currently active editable element.

for more details have a look on it 
                                                                                                                                                                       https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this issue as well, and found that setting the css property

```html
user-select: none;
```

on the tag with the click handler to run `execCommand` fixed the problem.

Seems like the issue is due to the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object having the wrong item selected (the focus changes) when you click an HTML tag that can be selected.